# Chrome extension has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check

Tags: cors, chrome

We've been using a third party Chrome extension from a vendor (Groove) to sync emails/calendar items with Salesforce. It has worked great for 12+ months but suddenly stopped working with various **Health Check** and **Reconnect** warning messages

- Following instructions, user attempted to reconnect. OAuth works fine but 3rd party system still shows health check / reconnect error
- Vendor support has us clearing cookies, reinstalling extension, etc and retrying to no avail. Eventually vendor support stumped.
- Inspecting Chrome Dev tools, we see:

  ```
  Access to fetch at https://mycompany.my.salesforce.com/apex/DaScoopComposer__GrooveMessageEvent

  from origin 'chrome-extension://fdkgjhmihbfpjgodmbmmmgmgnmemokda' 
   has been blocked by CORS policy: 
   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 

   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
   If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' 
     to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
  ```
- Checking the SFDC `Setup > CORS` shows the third party domain is allowed.
- SetupAudit Trail doesn't show any changes in other SFDC config

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our enterprise, Google Chrome is an enterprise-managed app and as such, every Chrome Extension requires pre-approval

- The 3rd party extension (Groove) had been pre-approved but ...
- IT had recently added URLs to the blocked hosts list for that extension within the `Google Managed Browser` config.  One of the blocked URLs was `mycompany.my.salesforce.com` !

Removing the blocked host that represents our PROD SFDC domain from the Google Managed Browser config resolved the issue

[image]